# How can I mute slack channels from the web API?

Tags: php, slack-api

I tried to mute slack channels with a call to the Slack API like this.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://slack.com/api/users.prefs.set";

    $POST_DATA = array(
        'token' => SLACK_TOKEN,
        'muted_channels' => TARGET_CHANNEL_ID,
    );

    $curl=curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POST_DATA));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $output= curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($output);
```

But, it does not work.

Comment: This is not an official Slack AP method. did you receive an "unknown_method" error?

Comment: No. I got a bunch of my user Information.
It's including muted_channels.   
`muted_channels":"Foo,Bar"`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. You found another undocumented API method, nice!
I tried it too, but could not get it to work either. Maybe setting "muted channels" it not support. I had the same effect on other methods, where only some of the parameters could be set.

Comment: I am documenting the "undocumented" Slack API methods on github and have added the "users.pref.get" variant. Check out the [github page](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc) if you like to add to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works.

You need to pass a JSON array of the preferences to be set with the `prefs` property.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://slack.com/api/users.prefs.set";

    $POST_DATA = array(
        'token' => SLACK_TOKEN,
        'prefs' => json_encode(array('muted_channels' => TARGET_CHANNEL_ID)),
    );

    $curl=curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($POST_DATA));
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    $output= curl_exec($curl);

    print_r($output);
```

I also added a documentation for [`users.prefs.set`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/users.prefs.set.md) to the [github](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc).